# How to connect to SSL vpn provided by FortiClient from linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vpn

I use Ubuntu almost exclusively for work. However, recently I am facing a challenge that forces me to use Windows. This is because the company demands that all connections to databases should be routed through SSL VPN provided by FortiClient. After some search I have come to a conclusion that FortiClient does not provide VPN functionality for linux machines (but correct me if I am wrong), so I have to stick with windows.

Is there any way to connect to an FortiClient SSL VPN from a linux machine? Or, can I establish vpn connection on a windows virtual machine, and route the traffic through it? If so, how?

Comment: https://forticlient.com/repoinfo

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities.. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [OpenfortiVPN](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn) on macos and linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official forticlient ssl VPN from [this](https://filestore.fortinet.com/forticlient/downloads/FortiClientFullVPNInstaller_6.4.0.0851.deb) link. This version has some bugs,for example resolving internal DNS server. [This](http://internal.enterprisecomponent.com/download/FortiClientSSLVPN/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2010.tar.gz) older version works for me.